# How not to load Tumbler service at XFCE login on Alpine Linux

Tags: xfce, services, alpine-linux, openrc

When I log in to XFCE, it seems `/usr/lib/tumbler-1/tumblerd` is started and uses relatively a large amount of memory. I do not need thumbnails. I want to remove it, but it is required for XFCE, so I cannot just uninstall the package.

I tried [this existing answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/543494/470399) and disabled Thunar thumbnail/rc file and rebooted, but `tumberd` was still loaded when I log in.

I thought of disabling the service, but I don't see a service with that name by `doas rc-service --list` when `htop` shows that `tumblerd` is running. Also, `tumblerd` seems to be terminated automatically after a while, so maybe it is not an always-running service.

I checked [the package's files](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=v3.16&name=tumbler&arch=x86_64&repo=community). What I saw was "dbus-1/service" like the following. Are they different from regular services? How can I stop it from getting loaded?

- /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Tumbler.Cache1.service
- /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Tumbler.Manager1.service
- /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Tumbler.Thumbnailer1.service

[image]